# Cannot reference main android Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having some major issues here after updating to android API 20, after creating a new android project on eclipse, I got flagged for tons of bus as you can see below

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 8  Java Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 12 Java Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 32 Java Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.   styles.xml  /testone/res/values-v14 line 8  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /testone/res/values line 7  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /testone/res/values-v11 line 7  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 13 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 19 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 29 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 3  Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 19 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 11 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 17 Java Problem
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MainActivity.java   /testone/src/com/example/testone    line 24 Java Problem
```

I already tried several methods that I found online but nothing seems to work. I tried: Fix project properties option doesnt do anything, when I try to add the library manually, I find that the appcompat_v7 is missing and when I try to add another library, the add library drop down menu is grayed out and cannot be selected. So I'm not really sure what to do here and i'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Did you try to clean your project then rebuild it?

Comment: just did that, still no go. Getting the same errors

Comment: follow this tutorial in the docs

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Try to create your project in API 19, if no issues, try upgrade again to API 20.

Comment: I tried creating it in API 19, still same errors and I tried updating the library like the tutorial in the link above. I downloaded the android support library and repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also stuck with the same issue few day ago,

I resolved the same issue by updating sdk to latest version 23.0.4. 
and extras: 
Android support Repository to rev.    6 
Android support Library    to rev.    20

first of all open up your Android sdk Manager from eclipse and download all latest sdk updates and extra downloads.

And then after downloading all updates , you have need to use a fresh Eclips editor because your existing eclipse will not let you successfully update from Android sdk tool 20 to 21.0.4 
Then just use a fresh eclips editor and set up updated android sdk path in the fresh eclips (the same one you have used in your last eclipse editor , you can find it at Window>> Prefrences >> Android).

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: ok i already have all the updates done but i dont understand what you mean by "fresh eclopse editor" what is that?

Comment: fresh means newly downloaded or previously never used eclipse editor,

Comment: I actually deleted eclipse entirely and re downloaded a fresh version with no plugins, I downloaded all the updates/plugins again and I am still having the same problem :(

Comment: Have you downloaded the android 4.4W (API 20) , try to use this Target android version. You can select it by right click on project >> Android >>  android 4.4W

Comment: "ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java "    is this the error now or something else

Comment: yes that same error is still there along with all the other error's listed above after I've installed a fresh copy and re installed all the libraries.

Comment: Can you confirm your Android support Repository & Android support Library  revision :  You can find the revision in the Android sdk manager Extras , just below all downloaded apis.

Comment: I just doubled checked and I do have both the support library and repository installed

Comment: Can you confirm that Android support Repository  rev is  6 , Android support Library  rev  is 20.

Comment: then try to delete bin and gen folder and then ckear and build project again , if again problem exist move your project to AndroidStudio . hopefully this will resolve your problem.